# Do we need to backup our important data in Blogger?

Tags: blogger, backup, online-backup

I remember reading somewhere that our emails in Gmail are safe from destruction (even if one of Google's server farms got burned by terrorists or something) because the data is basically replicated and stored securely in multiple multiple places so the data will never be gone. And there is no need to backup our emails in Gmail (unless we are worried that our passwords are compromised but that is a totally different issue).

I want to use Blogger as my "online cloud storage device", basically I want to have a place in the cloud where I can store data (and easily edit/add data from anywhere anytime). The problem is that this data is important and I cannot afford to wake up one day and have it gone.

Does the data (our blog posts) in Blogger provide the same kind of "data-security" as our emails in Gmail?

I know that Blogger is owned by Google but are there any official documents/terms describing the "safety" of our data with Blogger?

Comment: FYI: [There was a recent data loss at Google Mail](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-20037019-93.html), however *most* data has been restored but not all, don't count on it, just do your own backups. What if Google decides to stop its services tomorrow?

Comment: it is more possible for microsoft, apple, and facebook to stop their services than google don't you think so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this Blogger Status Report posted in May 2011](http://status.blogger.com/2011/05/blogger-incident-report-by-eddie.html) they replicate data of all blogs across multiple sites:

> Blogger maintains replicas (copies) of
>   blogs in multiple locations so if one
>   copy becomes unavailable — maybe due
>   to a cut network cable or loss of
>   power — blogs continue to remain
>   accessible.

However, if the data you store in Blogger is *that* important to you I would suggest you take a copy of the data yourself as piece of mind.

You can export your blog by clicking the `Settings` tab and then `Export blog`

[image: Settings Tab - Blogger]

Answer (score 1):

To archive your posts automatically, you can consider enabling a Blogger setting to email yourself every time you post to your blog.

Within Blogger, go to Settings  ›  Mobile and email. In the textarea **Email posts to**
you can enter a comma separated list of up to 10 email addresses to have your blog mailed to whenever you publish.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to have a separate back up of data that's important. So just as you'd have, say, keep several copies of photographs on your hard drive, on a DVD and possibly even in a Dropbox account, you'd want to keep the your own backups in addition to the Blogger ones.

If nothing else it will make recreating your blog on a different engine a bit easier should Blogger totally disappear.

Comment: well it's hard (and time-consuming) to make routine daily backups hence this question